# ANTLR4: Tree construction

Tags: antlr4

I am extending the baseClass Listener and am attempting to read in some values, however there doesnt seem to be any hierrarchy in the order.

A cut down version of my grammar is as follows:

```
start: config_options+
config_options: (KEY) EQUALS^ (PATH | ALPHANUM) (' '|'\r'|'\n')* ;

KEY: 'key' ;
EQUALS: '=' ;
ALPHANUM: [0-9a-zA-Z]+ ;
```

However the parse tree of this implementation is flat at the config_options level (Terminal level) i.e.the rule start has many children of config_options but EQUALS is not the root of subtrees of config_options, all of the TOKENS have the rule config_options as root node. How can I make one of the terminals a root node instead?

In this particular rule I dont want any of the spaces to be captured, I know that there is the -> skip directed for the lexer however there are some cases where I do want the space. i.e. in String '"'(ALPHANUM|' ')'"'

(Note: the ^ does not seem to work)

an example for input is:

key=abcdefg

key=90weata

key=acbefg9

All I want to do is extract the key and value pairs. I would expect that the '=' would be the root and the two children would be the key and the value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you generate your grammar, you should be getting a syntax error over the use of the `^` operator, which was removed in ANTLR 4. ANTLR 4 generates *parse trees*, the roots of which are implicitly defined by the rules in your grammar. In other words, for the grammar you gave above the parse tree nodes will be `start` and `config_options`.

The generated `config_options` rule will return an instance of `Config_optionsContext`, which contains the following methods:

- `KEY()` returns a [`TerminalNode`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/TerminalNode.html) for the `KEY` token.
- `EQUALS()` (same for the `EQUALS` token)
- `PATH()` (same for the `PATH` token)
- `ALPHANUM()` (same for the `ALPHANUM` token)

You can call `getSymbol()` on a `TerminalNode` to get the `Token` instance.

Comment: How would you be able to define a relationship between terminals? i.e get the children of the equals sign. Or is this not a valid idea in ANTLR4?
Is there a way to create an AST instead of a parse tree?

Comment: @user1932405, create an extra rule, `value` for example: `config_options: KEY EQUALS value ; value : (PATH | ALPHANUM) (' '|'\r'|'\n')* ;`

Comment: Oh okay, Thanks for that, so Ill have to create AST based on parse rules and not tokens.